# Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm getting a memory leak when I`m trying to reset a table view, I thought I could just put release before, but this doesn't help.

What do I need to do here ?

```
-(void) resetTable{

    recordOffset = 10;
    rOFactor = 0;
    booShowMoreCell = false; 
    self.transactionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // leak here
}
```

Comment: is transactionsArray a retained property?

Comment: The solution? Use ARC. It's the way of the future, and I have had absolutely no memory leaks while using it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that transactionsArray is a retained property, the problem you are having is that the NSMutableArray is being retained twice.

When you set a retained property it releases the old value, and retains the new (incoming) value. The alloc method also retains the object.

So

```
//   \/--- retain count = 2               \/-- retain count = 1
self.transactionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

The shortest way to resolve this is autorelease the NSMutableArray:

```
self.transactionsArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

There's a convenience method way for the above line:

```
self.transactionsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can't see a `[tableView release]`-call in this code, that's what's missing - you aren't releasing the `tableView` before allocating a new one on top of it. That means you're adding a retain count, without removing one first. Adding the `release` will fix the leak.

Answer (score 0):

On the first sight I would say that you just overwrite the pointer with a reference to a new object and forgetting the old reference which points to an object that was not released yet. As long as you do not use ARC you should use

```
[self.transactionsArray release]; // Be sure it was alloced before
self.transactionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Assuming that the property is a retained property, then the synthesized setter will take care of releasing the old value.